# Which would be best suited for Ruby on Rails Dev Projects - 32 bit or 64 bit Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, 64-bit, installation, 32-bit

I have a 4GB Ram, 500 gb hdd with a 64 bit OS running on an intel core 2 duo 2.2 Ghz processor.

I just had one clarification would all the tools(different editors etc.) and softwares(like RubyMine IDE etc.) related to Ruby on Rails projects support/run with the 64 bit OS version or should I go with the recommended 32 bit os installation of Ubuntu 11.10 as given in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download .

Also is the 64 bit only suited for AMD processors?(just a doubt as the download file name of this version has amd tagged to it.) Would it work with the aforementioned intel processor?

Kindly suggest, so that I could install the appropriate bit version of OS. I'm planning to go ahead with the Desktop version itself.

Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: The AMD thing is a weird naming thing in linux, It works as it should on an Intel system.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no reason not to use the 64-bit OS. Take the OS that works best with your computer. I have one machine running 32-bit and another 64-bit without any problems (both on 11.10).

Comment: :) @nathanvda..how do i know beforehand which OS works best with the comp..? Am i missing anything from your answer..?

Comment: Well: if your processor is capable of running a 64-bit OS, or want to use more than 4GB of RAM (sure!). If you can run 64-bit: do it. But some machines are still equiped with a  a 32-bit CPU. That would be the only reason holding you back in my experience.

Comment: The only concern I had was the dev tools supporting a 64 bit OS, as many s/w's on a general note work mainly for 32-bit OS. I specifically wanted to knw more about what is applicable in case of RoR...